# Not able to redirect to another intent in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to move to another intent as soon as I click on one list item. In the below example, I need to move to another intent `MatchingInterest` as soon as I clicked on Attributes list.

But somehow whenever I am clicking on Attributes list, it is not redirecting me towards `MatchingInterest page`. Any idea why is it happening?

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {

    private String user_id = "1234";

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { " Settings", " Attributes"}));
        getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //get selected items
        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        if(selectedValue.equals("Attributes")) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("USERID", user_id);
            Intent thesisProject = new Intent(getActivity(), MatchingInterest.class);
            thesisProject.putExtras(bundle);

            startActivity(thesisProject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does happen? Any errors, does it hit those lines if you debug, etc...?

Comment: No error, nothing.. That's what I am wondering.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint inside `onListItemClick()` to see what lines get hit?

Comment: Actually, my debug mode is not working somehow. Whenever I launch my app in debug mode, it keeps on waiting forever. So that is the reason I am always trying in Run mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new String[] { " Settings", " Attributes"}
```

You have space in from of both of them.

'Attrubutes' is not equal to ' Attributes'